# Random directions in pygame for multiple objects?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a number of dots burst out in random directions from the center using pygame. I'm generating random angles for each dot and translating them to a direction (new position in x and y).

This is the formula:
pos.x = pos.x + speed * cos(angle)
pos.y = pos.y + speed * sin(angle)

When they hit a window boundary, they rebound in a new random direction.
It seems to work well at the start but as soon as the number of dots (n) goes above a dozen or so, instead of bursting in n different directions, it forms patterns:

[5 dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mBI5.png), [2000 dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9OB7.png), [2000 dots after rebound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Xzu.png)

I've tested different random number generators; no change. Different window sizes; no change. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import os
import math
import random
import time

#create window
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500 #1680, 990
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Sim')
#set fps
FPS = 60
#load image, set scale, set position (at centre)
DOT_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'dot.png'))
DOT_WIDTH, DOT_HEIGHT = 5, 5
DOT = pygame.transform.scale(DOT_IMAGE, (DOT_WIDTH, DOT_HEIGHT))
#create copies of image, with centre position and random angle
n = 2000
dots = []
for i in range(n):
    dots.append({'position': pygame.Rect(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, DOT_WIDTH, DOT_HEIGHT), 
                    'angle': round(random.uniform(0, 360), 2)})
print(dots)
#draws black background and dots
def draw_window(dots):
    WIN.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for i in range(n):
        WIN.blit(DOT, (dots[i]['position'].x, dots[i]['position'].y))
    pygame.display.update()
#update position of images according to their set random angle at given speed
def update_pos(pos, speed):
    for i in range(n):
        pos[i]['position'].x = pos[i]['position'].x + round(speed*math.cos(math.radians(pos[i]['angle'])))
        pos[i]['position'].y = pos[i]['position'].y + round(speed*math.sin(math.radians(pos[i]['angle'])))
        if pos[i]['position'].x >= WIDTH:
            pos[i]['angle'] = round(random.uniform(90, 270), 2)
        elif pos[i]['position'].x <= 0:
            pos[i]['angle'] = round(random.uniform(270, 450), 2)
        elif pos[i]['position'].y >= HEIGHT:
            pos[i]['angle'] = round(random.uniform(180, 360), 2)
        elif pos[i]['position'].y <= 0:
            pos[i]['angle'] = round(random.uniform(0, 180), 2)
#draws trails behind images            
def draw_trails():
    pass
#run game
def main():
    #every frame:
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        ########################################################################
        update_pos(dots, 4)

        draw_window(dots)
        ########################################################################
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Those look like clusters to me, not patterns. Do you see the same clusters every time? I suspect there are too few points to form clusters below a threshold. When the number of points exceeds this threshold, the pattern-recognition part of your brain tells you it's forming a pattern but it's basically just random numbers.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I'm not sure it's just my brain. When released, they don't just go in clusters, they are going in the exact same direction. Besides, the picture I included shows this perfectly (2000 dots). Thanks a lot for your response (first question ever posted). I'll investigate your theory a bit more.

Comment: Turns out that if you increase the speed, it does seem a lot more random.

Comment: Alright! I'm intrigued by _"When released, they don't just go in clusters, they are going in the exact same direction"_. Nothing in your code seems to indicate that this would happen. Maybe [edit] your question to include a gif, and `print` the `pos[i]['angle']` values to see if they're the same? BTW, you can do `for dot in pos: dot['position'].x = ...` instead of iterating over the indices and then accessing as `pos[i]` -- this is more pythonic